# A question about Characteristic polynomial of $A^2$ , Diagonalizability, Minimal polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form, minimal-polynomials

Consider this question asked in my masters entrance for which I am preparing.

> Let A be a real matrix with characterstic polynomial $(X-1)^3$ . Choose correct statements:

(1) A is always diagonazable.

(2) If minimal polynomial of A is $(X-1)^3$ then A is diagonizable,

(3) Characterstic polynomial of $A^2$ is $(X-1)^3$ .

(4) If A has exactly 2 jordan blocks , then $(A-1)^2$ is diagonizable.

I have proved a false , c true . I don't know how to approach (b),(d)( which concept should be used?).

Kindly give a detailed answer for (D) as i am not good in Jordan Forms

If useful ,I followed Hoffman Kunze

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(2) is false. In fact, a matrix is diagonalizable iff its minimal polynomial has no repeated factors.

(4) is true. The key is that for a Jordan block $J$ associated with $\lambda$, the size of $J$ is equal to the smallest $k$ for which $(J- \lambda)^k = 0$. If there are exactly two Jordan blocks for a size $3$ matrix, then each block has size $2$ or smaller.

Comment: So, How does size less than  or equal to helps to prove that it is diagonalizable?

Comment: @Ben To answer what I assume you are trying to ask, the point is not to show that $(A - 1)$ is diagonalizable, but that $(A - 1)^2$ is diagonalizable because all blocks of $(A - 1)$ are of size at most $2$.

Comment: I am sorry for typo . I meant how does size less than or equal to 2 tells us that it will be diagonizable. I am not very good in concepts related to Jordan forms , So can you please tell me in  abit detail? Thanks!

Comment: @Ben My answer is the same. You seem to be implying that my argument is "because $(A - 1)$ has blocks with size less than or equal to $2$, $(A - 1)$ is diagonalizable". This is not the case, as I explain in my previous comment. If we can't establish that much, then no amount of detail would be helpful.

Comment: Don't want to waste your time so will write in as much detail as possible. for part 2 : Given is that A has exactly 2 jordan blocks. I understood following line :The key is that for a Jordan block J associated with λ, the size of J is equal to the smallest k for which $J^k =0$. and the line aferwards. But the question is : How did you used to prove that $(A-1)^2$ is diagonalizable ? Can you elaborate on that . I am not able to deduce it ? I hope I am making more sense now!

Comment: @Ben The point is that $(A - 1)^2 = 0$, which means that $(A - 1)^2$ is diagonalizable

Comment: @Ben Does that make things clearer?

Comment: How did you wrote $(A-1)^2 =0 $? What's the reasoning behind it?

Comment: @Ben If $J$ is the Jordan form of $A$, then what does $J - 1$ look like? Can you see that this implies that $(J - 1)^2 = 0$?

Comment: I got it why $(A-I)^2$ =0 but still I don't understand why it implies diagonalizability of $(A-I)^2$? It is my very humble request to you to help me!

Comment: @Ben The zero-matrix is a diagonal matrix. If $(A - I)^2 = 0$, then $(A - I)^2$ is diagonal (and therefore diagonalizable).